# Playing video in background of openGl application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, opengl-es

I found some tutorials about playing a fullscreen video on the iPhone, but I wonder if it is possible to play an embedded movie in the background of a openGl animated app?

The movie should just loop seamlessly and should not have any control buttons like play/pause/volume popping up while being played. If possible, then how about performance?

Answer (score 1):

1. Decode next video frame
2. Upload frame bitmap to texture
3. Disable depth buffer reads/writes
4. Draw screen-sized textured quad using frame texture
5. Re-enable depth buffer reads/writes
6. Render your regular scene
7. Go to #1

Comment: Thanks, but did you try this in practice? Sounds awfully slow, especially on older iPhones as per my experience writing anything to a texture brings the framerate to a near halt on those older devices, even when updating very small texture areas. Do you have any code for uploading the bitmap quickly?